# Duvida de lógica em C

Tags: c

Estou resolvendo um pequeno exercício em C que deve imprimir o antecessor e o sucessor de um número em tela. O antecessor imprime corretamente, mas o sucessor mostra sempre 108. independentemente do numero digitado. 
Imagino que seja uma espécie de lixo. Como se resolve isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int numero,antecessor,sucessor;
    printf("\n Escreva um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    antecessor=numero-1;
    sucessor+numero+1;
    printf("=============================================\n\n");
    printf("\n O antecessor do numero %d e %d\n\n", numero, antecessor);    
    printf("=============================================\n\n");
    printf("\n O sucessor do numero %d e %d\n\n", numero, sucessor);
    printf("=============================================\n\n");

system("pause");    
return(0);
}
```

EM TEMPO: Peço desculpas a todos.
O erro nada tinha a ver com lixo e sim com digitação errada por minha parte.
Só depois de postar é que vi que o segundo número (sucessor) estava recebendo erradamente a atribuição de valor.

Ao invés de eu escrever:

sucessor=numero+1

escrevi:

sucessor+numero+1

Comment: sucessor = numero + 1 e não sucessor + numero + 1

Comment: Pois é pmargeff... Só depois de postar a dúvida é que vi que se tratava de erro de digitação! Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

```
    antecessor=numero-1;
    sucessor+numero+1;             /* esta linha nao faz nada */
    printf("=============================================\n\n");
```

Observa bem a segunda linha do trecho acima :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta caro pmg ! Como pôde ver, foi dúvida de iniciante nível ZERO, destes que ainda erra atribuição de valor!! Mas obrigado pela atenção.